# Observer pattern imp

Tags: java, unit-testing, observer-pattern

I am doing a observer pattern as a homework but i am failing the Test.
I have been stacked for quite a while. If you could have a look at my code and give me an advice where I am wrong and what I am not doing as supposed. Cheers. Here is the code.

```
public class Share 
{
    /**@param poundsAndPences stores the monetary unit for the share.
     * @unique a  instance of the Share class responsible for the observer pattern*/
    private double poundsAndPences = 1.00;
    ArrayList<ShareWatcher> list = new ArrayList<ShareWatcher>();

    public boolean addShareWatcher(ShareWatcher sw)
    {
            list.add(sw); 
            if (list.contains(sw))
            {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean removeShareWatcher(ShareWatcher sw)
    {
        if(list.contains(sw))
        {
             list.remove(sw);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;  
        } 


    }

    /** Share(double poundsAndPences) private constructor.
     * 1-st pre-requisite for the multiple pattern 
     * takes and double value and initialized the local
     * variable with the one that have been passed
     * @param poundsAndPences sets the local variable with the current value*/
     Share()
    {
//        this.poundsAndPences = poundsAndPences;
//          changeState();
//        System.out.println("test: " + list);
    }

    /**getPoundsAndPences() is a getter method to. 
     * @return the poundsAndPences
     */
    public double getPrice() 
    {
        return poundsAndPences;
    }

    /**setPoundsAndPences(int poundsAndPences) is a mutator method.
     * @param poundsAndPences set the poundsAndPences passed to the
     * methods to the local ones 
     */
    public void setPrice(double poundsAndPences) 
    {
        this.poundsAndPences = poundsAndPences;
        changeState();
        updateShareWatcher();
    }

    public void changeState()
    {
        poundsAndPences = getPrice() ;
    }

    public void updateShareWatcher()
    {
//       System.out.println("list: " + list);
        int counter = 0;
        for(ShareWatcher sw: list)
        {
//            System.out.println("list test: "+ counter++  + "  %%% " + sw);
            sw.updatePrice(poundsAndPences);
//            System.out.println(list.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

this is the interface

```
public interface ShareWatcher 
{
    void updatePrice(double price);

}

public class BankManager implements ShareWatcher
{
     int portfolio = 0;
    /**
     * Buy value for bank manager.
     */
     static double BM_BUY = 1.00;

    /**
     * Sell value for bank manager.
     */
     static double BM_SELL = 4.00;

    /**
     * Increment value for bank manager.
     */
     static int BM_INCREMENT = 100;


    public BankManager(double BM_BUY, double BM_SELL, int BM_INCREMENT)
    {
        this.BM_BUY = BM_BUY;
        this.BM_SELL = BM_SELL;
        this.BM_INCREMENT = BM_INCREMENT;

        portfolio = 0;

//        updatePrice(portfolio);
    }


    public  int getPortfolio()
    {
        return portfolio;
    }

    public  void setPortfolio(int portfolio)
    {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
//        updatePrice(portfolio);
    }

    public void  updatePrice(double price)
    {
        if(price < 1.00)
        {
            BM_BUY = price;
            System.out.println("BankManager buy shares at: " + BM_BUY);

        }

        if(price > 4.00)
        {
            BM_SELL = price;
            System.out.println("BankManager sell shares at:" + BM_SELL);
        }
//        portfolio = price;
//        System.out.println("Update BankManager");
//        System.out.println("New value is: " + portfolio);
    }
}


public class StockBroker implements ShareWatcher
{
      int portfolio = 1;
     /**
     * Buy value for stock broker.
     */
     static double SB_BUY = 2.00;

    /**
     * Sell value for stock broker.
     */
     static double SB_SELL = 3.00;

    /**
     * Increment value for stock broker.
     */
     static int SB_INCREMENT = 500;

    StockBroker(double SB_BUY, double SB_SELL, int SB_INCREMENT)
    {
//        this.price = portfolio;
//        updatePrice(portfolio);
        this.SB_BUY = SB_BUY;
        this.SB_SELL = SB_SELL;
        this.SB_INCREMENT = SB_INCREMENT;
        portfolio = 0;

//        updatePrice(portfolio);
    }
    public  int getPortfolio() 
    {
        return portfolio ;
    }

    public  void setPortfolio(int portfolio) 
    {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
    }

    public void updatePrice(double price)
    {
//        StockBroker sb = new StockBroker(SB_BUY, SB_SELL, SB_INCREMENT);

        if(price < 2.00)
        {
           SB_BUY = price;
            System.out.println("StockBroker buy shares at: " + SB_BUY);
        }

        if(price > 3.00)
        {
            SB_SELL= price;
            System.out.println("StockBroker sell shares at:" + SB_SELL);
        }
        portfolio = SB_INCREMENT;
//        System.out.println("Update StockBroker");
//        System.out.println("New value is: " + portfolio);
    }

}
```

and here is the testing class

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Ignore;

/** A set of unit tests that check the solution to the SILVER task.
 *
 */
public class ShareTest {

/**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE1 = 4.01;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE2 = 0.99;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE3 = 2.12;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE4 = 1.89;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE5 = 1.83;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE6 = 2.78;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE7 = 14.12;
    /**
     * Arbitrary stock price value for testing. 
     */
    final static double PRICE8 = 6.99;

    /**
     * Buy value for bank manager.
     */
    final static double BM_BUY = 1.00;

    /**
     * Sell value for bank manager.
     */
    final static double BM_SELL = 4.00;

    /**
     * Increment value for bank manager.
     */
    final static int BM_INCREMENT = 100;

    /**
     * Buy value for stock broker.
     */
    final static double SB_BUY = 2.00;

    /**
     * Sell value for stock broker.
     */
    final static double SB_SELL = 3.00;

    /**
     * Increment value for stock broker.
     */
    final static int SB_INCREMENT = 500;
  public ShareTest(){
  }

  @Test
    public void testChangePrice1() {
        final Share share = new Share();
        final BankManager bankManager = new BankManager(BM_BUY, BM_SELL, BM_INCREMENT);
        final StockBroker stockBroker = new StockBroker(SB_BUY, SB_SELL, SB_INCREMENT);
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(bankManager));
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(stockBroker));
        share.setPrice(PRICE5);
        final int expectedValue1 = 0;
//        System.out.println("*****BankManager " + bankManager.getPortfolio());
        assertEquals(bankManager.getPortfolio(), expectedValue1);
        final int expectedValue2 = 500;
        System.out.println("*****StockBroker " + stockBroker.getPortfolio());
        assertEquals(stockBroker.getPortfolio(), expectedValue2);
    }

    /**
     * Test of changePrice method, of class Share. A similar test to above. More 
     * changes this time.
     */
//    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void testChangePrice2() {
        final Share share = new Share();
        final BankManager bankManager = new BankManager(BM_BUY, BM_SELL, BM_INCREMENT);
        final StockBroker stockBroker = new StockBroker(SB_BUY, SB_SELL, SB_INCREMENT);
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(bankManager));
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(stockBroker));
        share.setPrice(PRICE3);
        share.setPrice(PRICE6);
        share.setPrice(PRICE8);
        final int expectedValue1 = 0;
        assertEquals(bankManager.getPortfolio(), expectedValue1);
        final int expectedValue2 = 0;
        assertEquals(stockBroker.getPortfolio(), expectedValue2);
    }


    /**
     * Test of changePrice method, of class Share. A similar test to above. More
     * changes this time.
     */
//    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void testChangePrice3() {
        final Share share = new Share();
        final BankManager bankManager = new BankManager(BM_BUY, BM_SELL, BM_INCREMENT);
        final StockBroker stockBroker = new StockBroker(SB_BUY, SB_SELL, SB_INCREMENT);
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(bankManager));
        assertTrue(share.addShareWatcher(stockBroker));
        share.setPrice(PRICE1);
        share.setPrice(PRICE4);
        share.setPrice(PRICE7);
        share.setPrice(PRICE2);
        final int expectedValue1 = 100;
        assertEquals(bankManager.getPortfolio(), expectedValue1);
        final int expectedValue2 = 500;
        assertEquals(stockBroker.getPortfolio(), expectedValue2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of your tests fails? Have you some output from a test run?

Comment: As the code is in the moment it is failing the testChangePrice2: Failed; expected<500> but was <0> for the stockBroker and testChangePrice3: Failed; expected<0> but was <100> for the bankManager. and the expected is what is printed and actual is what is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Switch `assertEquals(..., exptedValue);` to `assertEquals(exptedValue, ...);`. This doesn't change your failures, but follows the javadoc at [Class Assert](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) and fixes the reported output.

- In `BankManager`, you never change `portfolio`, so this is the reason for your first failure.
- In `StockBroker`, you set `portfolio` always to `SB_INCREMENT`, so this might be the reason for your second failure.

So in order for this to work, you must either adjust the `portfolio`, if the price changes or adjust the `expectedValue`s to your current implementation.

Comment: thanks for that, but as you said it doesn't change the faulures

Comment: i still do not see how i need to change the portfolio in order to pass the test...

Comment: I don't know either. Since this is a homework, there must be some description or requirement, how the portfolio should change when prices are set. Nobody can guess the relationship between changing prices and resulting portfolio.

Comment: Your `class Share` looks ok, so it's just the `updatePrice()` methods, which must be fixed.